# WPF bind DataContext in xaml to ViewModel in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have this simplified version of my app in XAML:

```
<UserControl
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:myApp.MyControls"    
      x:Class="myApp.View.MyItem"
      x:Name="testWind"
      Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="White">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox x:Name="GroupBox" Header="G" Grid.Row="0">
            <WrapPanel>
                <GroupBox x:Name="GroupBox11">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <uc:customControl1 Margin="0,4,0,0" 
                                           property1="{Binding prop1.property1}" 
                                           property2="{Binding prop1.property2}"
                                           property3="{Binding prop1.property3}"/>
                        <uc:customControl2 Margin="0,4,0,0" 
                                           property1="{Binding prop2.property1}" 
                                           property2="{Binding prop2.property2}"
                                           property3="{Binding prop2.property3}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </WrapPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In C# I have this:

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class MyItemViewModel
    {
        public object prop1 { get; set; }
        public object prop2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In MyItem.cs I do this:

```
namespace MyApp.View
{
    public partial class MyItem : UserControl
    {
        public MyItem()
        {
             this.InitializeComponent();
             MyItemViewModel vm = new MyItemViewModel();
             vm.prop1 = new blah blah(); // setting properties
             vm.prop2 = new blah blah(); // setting properties
             this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

When you end up having too many controls, this can become difficult to maintain. So, how can I tell XAML to do something like:

```
    <uc:customControl1 Margin="0,4,0,0" DataContext="prop1"/>
    <uc:customControl2 Margin="0,4,0,0" DataContext="prop2"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just give each control a unique name

```
<uc:customControl1 x:Name="mycontrol1" Margin="0,4,0,0" DataContext="prop1"/>
<uc:customControl2 x:Name="mycontrol2" Margin="0,4,0,0" DataContext="prop2"/>
```

then in your code , you could just change the data context

```
   mycontrol1.DataContext = vm1;
   mycontrol2.DataContext = vm2;
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried that and it doesnt seem to work.
How does the DataContext="prop1" in XAML relate to mycontrol1.DataContext=vm1 in C# besides the name? 
Why do you set a "prop1" name in XAML, while in C# its vm1?

Comment: @vark , i was just following your example. vm1 and vm2 represent different data contexts.

Comment: hey andrew, yes i have understood this. however i cannot make this work. i have built a small sample project illustrating both methods here:http://www.2shared.com/file/8688933/866fc885/usercustom.html. is there something i have missed out of your explanation?